# How can I add the mentioned role to a member?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

In my discord bot I was trying to make an `add command` so it adds the `member` self-roles.

I know how to add `roles` to the `member` but I **don't** know how can I add a `member` the `role` that was `mentioned`!

This is my code so far:

```
if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'add')) {
    let rolename = msg.content.slice(5).trim()
    let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === rolename)

    //The code will work if the member only types the name of the role without mention
    //so it is also a solution if someone knows how to change the mention to a name
    msg.member.roles.add(role)
}
```

Comment: Use the [`mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) property of the `message` object and check if the mention has a role in it. If yes, then store the value and then add it to the member. And `<MessageMentions>#roles#first()` will give you the first mentioned role.

Comment: Oh...Thanks that solved the issue Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: @Radnerus Friendly reminder: You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) property of the `message` object and check if the `mention` has a `role` in it.

If yes, then **store** the value and then **add** it to the `member`. And `<MessageMentions>#roles#first()` will give you the `first mentioned role` from the collection of `roles`.